# Problem creating a text file with name provided by input

Tags: python, file, operation

i am creating a txt file based on user input,But it creates files without any format,  i am new to python can anyone help me..

```
import os
name = input("Name :")
roll = input("Roll No :")
branch = input("Branch :")

add ="name :" + name + "\n" +"Roll No :" + roll +"\n" +"Branch :"+branch

f = open(name,"a+")

m = os.path.join(name +".txt")
f.write(add)
```

want to get `name` `+` ".txt"  file for each user

output now is `name`

Comment: You don't do anything with `m`

Comment: f is opening the file, that is what creates the name, m does nothing. You have to add the ".txt" to f, the answer below is the correct version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
name = input("Name :")
roll = input("Roll No :")
branch = input("Branch :")

add ="name :" + name + "\n" +"Roll No :" + roll +"\n" +"Branch :"+branch

f = open(name + ".txt","a+") # This is where you are opening the file

# Below line is not contributing to the posted code at all
# m = os.path.join(name +".txt")

f.write(add)
f.close()
```